# multiple id in jsonb column sql. supabase

Tags: sql, mysql, supabase, supabase-database

I have to tables in my database. One is **Workout** the other is **exercise** the structure as the following:

```
exercise_TABLE
```

| id | name | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | aaa |
| 2 | bbb | BBB |
| 3 | ccc | CCC |

```
workout_TABLE
```

| id | val_1 | exercise_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | aaa |
| 2 | bbb | BBB |
| 3 | ccc | CCC |

the relation here is the exercise.id to workout.exercise_id

So, i want to add multiple **exercises ids** in the **workout table** so the output should be like this

```
    workout_TABLE
```

| id | val_1 | exercise_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 1,2,3,4 |
| 2 | bbb | BBB |
| 3 | ccc | CCC |

**1,2,3,4** here are the exercises ids I want to store

Comment: Please add the expected output

Comment: @SelVazi exercise_id in the workout table is the expected output

Comment: Your query is not very clear! Where do you get `1,2,3,4,5`, and how do your tables relate to each other? expected outputs should match simple data

Comment: @SelVazi I've updated the question please take a second look

Comment: Hi - you should never put multiple values in a single column in a relational database. Your design looks wrong anyway. 1) If an exercise can only be part of a single workout then workout_id should be an FK on Exercise 2) If an Exercise can be associated to multiple Workouts then you need an intersection table that sits between your two tables

Comment: You can watch this video to learn how to create one-to-many relationships in Supabase. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5VrF9OVQ6rg